# Regsvr32 fails to find the dll in the current folder

Tags: windows, com, regsvr32

When I use "regsvr32 foo.dll" i get a "The specified module cannot be
found" error.

The error is being caused because regsvr32 cannot find
the file even though it is the current folder.

I have specified the full path, and it still doen't work. Any ideas????

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can happen if `foo.dll` has a depenency on `bar.dll` and it's actually `bar.dll` that can't be found.

Try using `depends.exe` from MSVC to check the dependencies of `foo.dll` and see if any are missing.

Another option is to download and run [FileMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx).  Then run `regsvr32` again and see which file/module it fails to find.  This should definitely track it down.

Answer (score 6):

On the 64bit OSes, Dependency Walker has been uninformative for me; and `FileMon` has been replaced by Process Monitor (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon to download the utility).  Here is how I was able to find the missing references using Process Monitor:

[image: ProcMon Toolbar for the Filter Dialog]

Open the Filter Dialog either from the toolbar or the menu.

[image: ProcMon Filter Dialog]

Add the `Process Name` of `regsvr32.exe` to the filter list and remove any `PID` filters.

[image: ProcMon Clear Toolbar Button]

Clear the list, ...

[image: ProcMon Capture Toolbar Button]

... turn on Capturing, if it is not already on.

Run your `regsvr32.exe` command from a console window.  Once complete, you might want to toggle the capture off.

[image: missing reference lines]

Look for the missing reference after `regsvr32` has loaded your DLL.

Answer (score 0):

In my case REGSVR32 claimed "no file found..." when the DLL's (actually legacy VB OCX's) were in SYSTEM32.  After moving them to a another directory REGSVR32 succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

In some versions of Windows10 the file to be registered by SYSWOW64\REGSVR32 has to reside in **SYSWOW64**